# Resolving references | Exe/Dll vs Lib

Tags: c++, build, msbuild

All this is in the context of msbuild, but I'm sure the general principle applies regardless of build system.  I was updating some vcxproj files to build some unit tests (a DLL) and was encountering a LNK2001 error saying that there was no reference to some function found in dbghelp.lib (Windows SDK).

When comparing my unittest vcxproj file to the vcxproj associated with my test content (a Lib), I didn't see any linking to dbghelp.lib. I was informed by my coworker that in a Lib, you only have to resolve references that you use in the lib, but for Exe/Dll, you need to resolve ALL references.

My guess is that in a Lib, what references are used controlled by the lib's author, so only the references that are used need to be resolved.  For Exe/Dlls, there's no such guarantee so ALL references need to be resolved.  Does that sound right and is there more to it than that?

Related, are there any good book recommendations that covers this topic if I wanted to learn more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your main question is yes, that is all there is to it. You can get around the need for static symbol resolution by using dynamic resolution instead (LoadLibrary/GetProcAddress).

The topic you ask about is such a simple and integral part of builds that I am not aware of anything treating it as a main topic, nor anything that treats windows-isms in detail. There is the book "Linkers and Loaders" by John R. Levine that provides a more unix-like treatment of the topic. And there are tool-specific document sets.

For Microsoft tools I would highly recommend looking at the Visual Studio material at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/?view=vs-2017#pivot=get-started&panel=get-started1 (Iprefered the older MSDN but have seen material disappearing from there, and I use a local copy of an older MSDN document set so can't tell you in detail where to find material about the linker options at learn.microsoft.com).